# Pig killing data nodes while loading a lot of files

Tags: mapreduce, hdfs, apache-pig

I have a script that tries to get the times that users start/end their days based on log files.  The job always fails before it completes and seems to knock 2 data nodes down every time.

The load portion of the script:

```
log = LOAD '$data' USING SieveLoader('@source_host', 'node', 'uid', 'long_timestamp', 'type');
log_map = FILTER log BY $0 IS NOT NULL AND $0#'uid' IS NOT NULL AND $0#'type'=='USER_AUTH';
```

There are about 6500 files that we are reading from, so it seems to spawn about that many map tasks.  The SieveLoader is a custom UDF that loads a line, passes it to an existing method that parses fields from the line and returns them in a map.  The parameters passed in are to limit the size of the map to only those fields with which we are concerned.

Our cluster has 5 data nodes.  We have quad cores and each node allows 3 map/reduce slots for a total of 15.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean "knock 2 data nodes down every time"? They reboot? The process dies? What do the logs say? Nothing you are doing in your Pig is that crazy so it's definitely a systems issue.

Comment: The data nodes go down according to the name node monitoring page.  The process eventually shuts down due to enough failed jobs from being sent to those nodes.  I am pretty new to Hadoop and am not an administrator for the system so I don't know all the configuration specifics.